# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Express

Tags: node.js, express, file, project, mean-stack

[This file contain the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buk9g.png)

[This file contains the directory settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiCbs.png)

While trying to add static images to the home.ejs folder i am constantly getting this error:-

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

I tried to use the `app.use(express.static('public'))` but the issue still persist.

This is the path i used:

```
assets/img/hero.jpg
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this issue and is there is something wrong with file structure or i made mistake while referencing the file name.

Comment: I am not sure from which directory you are executing that code in the second screenshot. Is it definitely on the same level as `/assets/`? If so, have you tried `./assets/`?

Comment: I am tying to get the image at home.ejs which is under views/pages the image is under  assets/img. Yes i tried ./assets but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to set the path

```
app.set('/views',path.join(__dirname,'/views'))
```

then we can use image by using this path:

```
img/hero.jpg
```